# Getting Objects from database in Symfony2

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

I had read somewhere some day that symfony2/Doctrine2 has a method(i don't remember the method name now) that fetches all "like" objects that we specify.. 
For example, I have `User entity` that has `userName` , `password`, `name`, `state` and `city` as properties.. For getting all Users who has `name = "vinay"` and `state = "karnataka"`, the steps goes like this,,

```
$user = new User();
$user->setName("vinay");
$user->setState("karnataka");

$query = $em->dontKnowTheMethod($user);
$usersList = $query->getResult();
```

`$usersList` should contain all the users whose `name = "vinay"` and `state = "karnataka"`

I searched for hours but Im not getting that method.. Im sure I had read about that method long back but I cannot recall now..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try googling your question before posting here, this question is very basic and in every doc

Comment: Indeed this is a basic concept that is clearly documented in the Symfony2 cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start studying doctrine and symfony.

```
$user = new User();
$user->setName("vinay");
$user->setState("karnataka");

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();

$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourWhateverBundle:User');
$userResult = $repo->findAll(['name' => 'vinay', 'state' => 'karnataka'])

if (!$userResult instanceof User) {
   echo 'No result found';
} else {
   // Do whatever you want with $userResult
}
```

Comment: [Check this out](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php).

Comment: if (!$userResult instanceof User) always true.. Because it is an instance of Array i guess..

Comment: If what you're looking for exists in DB then it will be true otherwise not. You can always check what it is with `echo gettype($userResult);`

Comment: No No.. What Im telling is that $userResult is an instanceof array right..?

Comment: Depending on result, it can be either instance of User class, array or something else. If it is an instance then use `foreach ($userResult as $usr) { echo $usr->getName(); }` to loop thru the results.

Comment: Hi @BentCoder possibily a typo in your answer? the method `findAll` don't accept parameters, possbily you want say `findBy`?

Comment: Check the link I've added in my comment above.

Comment: This is what i used,  findOneBy (array ());